# Sum of integers, not counting 13 and the number after 13

Tags: c

I am new to C and trying to Write a program that reads in a series of integers until a value of zero is encountered and then prints the sum of all the numbers except those that are equal to 13 or that come immediately after a 13. It is guaranteed that there is at least one zero in the input.
At most 100 lines of input, each line containing a single integer. At least one of the lines will contain the integer 0.
My code is like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{

    int sum = 0;
    int data[100];
    int i = 0;
    scanf("%d\n", &data[i]);
    while (data[i] != 0 && i < 100)  {

        if (data[i] == 13) {
            sum = sum;
        } else if (i > 0 && data[i-1] == 13) {
            sum = sum;
        } else {
            sum += data[i];
            i++;
        }
        scanf("%d\n", &data[i]);
    }
    printf("%d",sum);

}
```

I tried to get rid of the number after 13 but failed... Please help.

Comment: `sum = sum;` is doing zero work.

Comment: ..or propely format the code so it doesn't look like the 2nd scanf is otrside he loop.

Comment: Your are not incrementing `i` in every code path in the loop, so the `while` condition will not change and you will have an endless loop. By the way, it would help if you wrote more details than just "but failed". You should make yourself familiar with a debugger and run your program in the debugger and walk through it step by step. That helps a lot when you try to understand what your program does and why it does not do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easiest to collect all conditions in one boolean expression of the if-statement:

```
        if (data[i] != 13 && (i == 0 || data[i-1] != 13){
            sum += data[i];
        }
        i++;
```

... and move `i` outside the if body.

Comment: No, this is not easier. The bug in your code (it ignores data[0]) illustrates this :).

Comment: @WernerHenze, although the condition is now correct, it isn't easy to read anymore and I needed my boolean algebra to transform the original into this condition. The problem with logic is that it is so logical...

Answer (score 4):

You could also try this:

```
// extra flag outside loop
int found13 = 0;

while (data[i] != 0 && i < 100)  {
    if (data[i] == 13) {
        found13 = 1; // set flag
    } else if (found13) {
        found13 = 0; // clear flag
    } else {
        sum += data[i];
        i++;
    }
    scanf("%d\n", &data[i]);
}
```

Improvements:

- Doesn't peek back at the previous element
- Doesn't need to constantly check `i > 0`):

---

EDIT: further refactor

```
int sum = 0;
int found13 = 0;
int data;

while (scanf("%d\n", &data) == 1 && data != 0) {
    if (data == 13) {
        found13 = 1; // set flag
    } else if (found13) {
        found13 = 0; // clear flag
    } else {
        sum += data;
    }
}
```

Improvements:

- As `@PaulOgilvie` pointed out, you no longer need an array to store your results
- ... neither do you need `i`
- ... nor the extra call to `scanf` outside the loop
- Now works for any number of inputs

Comment: Then he doesn't need an array.

Comment: C has `bool` in `stdbool.h`. That is better than an `int` with `0`and `1`.

Comment: You found an elegant solution.